# How can I connect to the external database in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have a php script ready on the server which will fetch the records from the external database. I want this records to be displayed on UITableView. I am new in Swift, followed my chapters online but cant get things work. I have created a model in the swift, defining the variables. I created the tableview on the storyboard, but dont have a clue how to call it. On one of the websites, I came across some hints and I am able to print the output fetched from the database (however, my model was not used in this case). Now I need to show it on each cell dynamically. Please let me know how can it be solved. Thanks for your time in advance :)

```
//my model 
import Foundation
import UIKit


    class Group : NSObject {
        var groupID: Int
        var groupName: String
        var groupImg: UIImage?
        var total: Int

        init(groupID: Int, groupName: String,groupImg: UIImage, total: Int ) {

            self.groupID = groupID
            self.groupName = groupName
            self.groupImg = groupImg
            self.total = total
        }
    }
```

I have cleared my ViewController and has basic setting in it.

Comment: Search for `URLSession` and `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`. There are thousands of examples here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to do a web request to your servers script. You should use URLSession or use something like the Alamofire or AFNetworking libraries which will do a lot of the web request lifting for you. I'd recommend using URLSession as this will teach you what's going on under the hood. Once you have done a Get or Post request to your server script your server will return a response. I would also recommend that your PHP script gets the data from your server and returns JSON format which your app will need to parse to present and work with the data.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex said its absolutely correct. Adding something more, you do not need to worry about connecting with database, all you need is the **url**. You will need to send a request either **get** or **post** or **put** etc with the **url** and then you will get some kind of return , most possible **json** return, coz most of the api provider provide **json** return, or whoever is designing the database for you he will fetch the data with **php** and will convert it to **json**. So get easy with **json** you have to deal with it everyday. After getting some kind of **json** return you need to convert those **json** response to **swift** object, that why you made that mode data but you don't know what to do with that. As @Alex said, there are some libraries which make networking call very easy, like **Alamofire** . You can use **swift** raw coding for networking call like **dataTask** but its really tedious. Study more and you will be fine soon. Here is a link of a great book, you can try that : [iOS Apps With REST API](https://leanpub.com/iosappswithrest)

Comment: IMHO it's *really* much more *tedious* to have no clue at all what the copied&pasted code actually does. It's worth it to gain some knowledge in *raw coding* ;-)

Comment: obviously everybody need to learn but eventually you would not use that do you ?

Comment: This is how we learn guys. I would have prob asked the same question 6 years ago lol :-)